# Go To Anchor on Load ( if else statement)

Tags: javascript, anchor, onload

Hi I have a page that navigates using anchors.  On load the index page (A) needs to jump to anchor. Fine I can do this with on load function but coming back to the page A from page B I want to jump to a different anchor.  I have this working:

```
    <!-- go to Anchor -->
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function goToAnchor() {
    var urllocation = location.href;
    if(urllocation.indexOf("#top") > -1){
        window.location.hash="top";
    } else {
    window.location.hash="middle";
    }
}
    </script>
```

`#middle` is the anchor to use when coming from a link that contains no anchor (or from typing the address into the url bar).  I want to add three more 'if's'.  I am fairly new at js so bear with me if I am doing something silly.  I tried this:

```
function goToAnchor() {
    var urllocation = location.href;        
if(urllocation.indexOf("#right") > -1){
        window.location.hash="right"; 
    } else {
    window.location.hash="middle";
    }
    if(urllocation.indexOf("#bottom") > -1){
        window.location.hash="bottom"; 
    } else {
    window.location.hash="middle";
    }
    if(urllocation.indexOf("#left") > -1){
        window.location.hash="left"; 
    } else {
    window.location.hash="middle";
    }
```

But not joy, the js breaks and no longer goes to #middle on page load.

I tried a wild card approach:

```
function goToAnchor() {
var urllocation = location.href;
if(urllocation.indexOf("#.") > -1){
    window.location.hash=".";
} else {
window.location.hash="middle";
}
```

}

Again, no joy.

Any help please.. thanks kindly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure I understand the effect you are trying to achieve (since `window.location.hash` should already contain the hash part of your url), but your code should probably rather be

```
function goToAnchor() {
    var urllocation = location.href;        
    if (urllocation.indexOf("#right") > -1) {
        window.location.hash = "right"; 
    } else if (urllocation.indexOf("#bottom") > -1) {
        window.location.hash = "bottom";
    } else if(urllocation.indexOf("#left") > -1) {
        window.location.hash = "left";
    } else {
        window.location.hash = "middle";
    }
}
```

I am also guessing that your 'wild card' approach is meant to use regular expressions:

```
function goToAnchor() {
    var urllocation = location.href;
    var hashMatch = urllocation.match(/#(.*)/)
    if (hashMatch){
        window.location.hash = hashMatch[1];
    } else {
        window.location.hash = "middle";
    }
}
```

Again, I don't quite see what effect this code should have, since `window.location.hash` will probably have the same value before and after the assignment.

Comment: @ Julian D.

Perfect, the wild card approach works as I wanted.  I know it was something simple I was massing.  As for the if else approach, I cad never thought of that before...

Thanks to all for quick replies.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to go back to the hash in the URL, have you tried something like this?

```
var hash = window.location.hash || "middle"; //Get current hash or default to "middle" if no hash is currently set
window.location.hash = +new Date() + ""; //Remove the hash and set it to some random value
window.location.hash = hash; //Set to the old hash
```

Comment: is `= +new Date()` a syntax i don't know about, or a mistype?

Comment: The `+` operator basically means "cast this to an integer", which turns the date object into a numeric timestamp.

Comment: @jbabey like apsillers said, it's a little bit of hackish magic. It calls `.valueOf` on an object and adds the other operand (0 in this case because I didn't put anything before the `+`). That could be rewritten as `new Date().valueOf().toString()`.

Comment: @Xeon06 nifty, though i don't think i'd ever use it because i'd forget what it does the next day :P

Comment: @jbabey if you really want to look cool, you also don't need the parenthesis on the constructor if there are no parameters. So `+new Date;`